# How to write RewriteCond and RewriteRule for changing url www to non-www and http to https?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, url-rewrite-module

In Apache's httpd.conf file, how to rewrite module for making url's www to non-www and force http to https?
When I tried below, it becomes infinite redirection error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from www/http to non-www/https, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: I tried your answer bur, it caused ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on browser

Comment: @Jaylee are you sure you are getting this error with my code? Actually I tested this on my apache, it is working fine and there is no chance for the redirect loop error.